# first download image button click is downloading .html file in react.js - next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, blob

This is the component I reproduced:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function Home() {
  const [downloadURL, setDownloadURL] = useState("");

  const download = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/test.jpg", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {},
    });
    const blob = await result.blob();
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    setDownloadURL(url);
  };

  const handleDownload = async (e) => {
    try {
      await download();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className=" bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity flex flex-col justify-center  items-center">
      <Image src="/test.jpg" width={500} height={600} className="mb-2 " />
      <button
        onClick={handleDownload}
        type="button"
        className="flex-1 content-center text-center bg-indigo-600 py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
      >
        <a href={downloadURL} download={"test"}>
          Download Image
        </a>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

in the first click, I download `.html` file and in next clicks I get the image downloaded. but I could not figure out what is causing the first click downloading the `html` file.

[reproducible github repo](https://github.com/yilmazbingo/stackoverflow-download-question)

[image]

Comment: Event bubbling, <a download> is inside of the <button>, so when you click - default <a download> handler is executed, with empty downloadURL due to initial state, then event is propagated up to the button - now button onClick is executed, setting the downloadURL and etc but actual download event is already happened till that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few mistakes with that approach:

1. Event bubbling, the `click` event is handled by `<a>` before the `<button>`'s onClick.
2. Dependency on a state variable changed during 1 click event, you are trying to change `<a>` href which is bind to state, but the state is not updated immediatelly, it will be updated only on next render, but the click event will not wait for that (skipping the fact it is done with async operation).

What I recommend: remove `<a>` completely and use old classic [download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server) function which creates `<a>` on the fly and executes "click" on it:

```js
function Home() {
  const download = (filename, content) => {
    var element = document.createElement("a");
    element.setAttribute("href", content);
    element.setAttribute("download", filename);
    element.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
  };

  const handleDownload = async (e) => {
    try {
      const result = await fetch("assets/test.png", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {}
      });
      const blob = await result.blob();
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      download("test", url);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <img src="/assets/test.png" width={100} height={100} />
      <button onClick={handleDownload} type="button">
        Download Image
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React dynamic download]

Sorry for simplifying your code a bit.